What moderator tools exist to control retaliatory close votes?
Several individuals with time on their hands can practically paralyze work of the whole meta.
Users should not allege close voters are mindless or malicious or otherwise not acting in good faith
What tools do moderators have to address this situation? For example, can moderators disable close votes for certain users? Can a limit (per week) be applied for close votes?

Okay, I've retagged your question to the appropriate tag. By the way, it's extremely weird that it would be asking you for that specific tag - normally, it should give you a choice of four required tags. Can you please provide a screenshot of what error you received when trying to use one of the three other options?

It was previously requested and de facto declined by the network's then-leader. A later post requesting the same thing was also de facto declined - it was closed as a duplicate of the former link by a then-staff member.

I'm not really sure why you've posted the link to the Meta Philosophy Q&A. Can you add some context?

@Anerdw Apparently there is a big stink on philosophy meta, and it’s started leaking here.

Erm, why almost instantly accept an ”answer" that doesn’t address the question and just puts a spotlight on unrelated discussions? Does this question actually look for input or just exist to promote the conflict?

By accepting the recently posted Community Wiki answer that has absolutely nothing to do with your question as written you've indicated that the question you're really asking is about whatever issue is going on on [philosophy.se] and [philosophy.meta.se]. As such, you've demonstrated that your real question here is about a single site, which makes this question off-topic here on Meta Stack Exchange. I have, thus, downvoted and voted to close.

@MisterMiyagi - A reasonable question (from my point of view) quickly turned into a street brawl. This last action was the end of the conversation.

To get right to the point, moderators do not have a specific tool to "turn off" or limit close votes from individual users. The only tool to halt problematic privilege use is an account suspension. Ideally, it should never get to that point though. We should be able to solve for this with discussion if it's widespread, and private moderator messages if it's not.
If you notice that there's a trend from one specific user who's casting close votes inappropriately, then you should flag one of their posts and explain the problem, providing examples. Moderators can reach out privately or issue a suspension at this point if they find your claim to be true.
If, instead, you're noticing that there's a trend of seemingly incorrect close votes on questions from multiple users, this is what your per-site meta is for. Bring up these instances there, speaking broadly. Do not name-and-shame - we don't tolerate that here on Meta SE, and I'd encourage other site metas not to tolerate it there either. Link to these questions, which should consist of at least a few (though ideally more), and explain why you think these closures are incorrect. Give proper reasoning, ideally citing existing site policy, and request that they be reopened. Try and guide folks to be on the same page you are regarding what qualifies for closure and what doesn't.
My only other bit of advice, if you do approach your meta site with these problems, is to be open to pushback. Understand that these close voters had a reason for voting to close in the places they did. You don't know what they were thinking when they chose to close these questions, so... Ask them. Get them involved in the conversation and get community consensus on a path forward. Point to these discussions, and the consensus reached there, if future problems arise. That's what Meta's all about.

For the post?
We can reopen unilaterally, or lock it in some way
For the user? If someone is clearly disruptive we can moderator message or suspend.
There's no way, other than review banning to do fine grained reduction of privileges like closure.

You can ban users who don't have the privilege to edit posts from suggesting edits. Of course, it's meaningless if the user is on the cusp of earning that privilege, but if they aren't, then it's another fine-grained reduction.

retalitatory/tactical usage of closevotes is disruptive - if its enough that someone needs to be stopped from closing a post.

Suspensions would be effective in suppressing close voting abuse. Maybe there should be more tooling to detect close vote misuse though.
